# How to make vim folding not open when typing brackets

Tags: vim

I am using vim and foldmethod=syntax; When I type brackets somewhere in my code, it immediately opens all following folds. I can see why that happens: the open bracket changes the correspondences of the other brackets and all the folds change at the same time. Can I somehow prevent that? I don't know, maybe something like a delay before all the folds are opened?

Edit:

Vim version (output of vim --version):

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 01 2022 09:16:32)
>
> Included patches: 1-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does `set foldclose=all` helps?

Comment: foldclose=all kind of does solve this, but at the cost of closing automatically everything everywhere, which isn't really what I want either (like when I enter a function, I want to see the whole body to easily navigate to the point I need to edit, or sometime have two function definitions open at the same time)

Comment: hmm. maybe the use of a plugin which does automatically insert a closing bracket after the cursor might help?

Comment: I am not sure if that would help, probably depends on how the plugin is implemented; Currently, I am using a macro, that inserts a for cycle with full body and all the brackets already there, but the split second during the macro execution still opens all the following folds. (that said, I have no idea how this would be implemented in a plugin, so maybe that would work; still, this is more of a workaround than a solution. Plus, I'd prefer my editor not do that)

Comment: I am curious about this too, but I use fdm=marker (i.e., "{{{" and "}}}"). My current kludge is that I type the closing brackets `}` first.  Sometimes the folds open; and then, when I type the opening brackets `{`, the folds that got opened all close up again.  There must be a better way.

Comment: @m_mlvx nice trick, I changed at least my for cycle macro so that it doesn't open the folds anymore

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
inoremap { }<left>{
```

as mentioned by @eff.

`inoremap { {}<left>` seems not to work any more.

````
You may also re-map `<cr>` to smartly make `{}` a block

```vim
inoremap <expr> <cr> MapEnterKey()

function! MapEnterKey()
  let line = getline('.')
  let col_pos = col('.')
  let prev_char = line[col_pos-2]
  let next_char = line[col_pos-1]
  if prev_char == '{' && next_char == '}'
    return "\<cr>\<esc>O"
  else
    return "\<cr>"
  endif
endfunction
````

Comment: not sure why, but the <left> still doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you share your Vim and OS version? There may be differences between versions.

Comment: I would think "{}<left>" will still trigger the issue (as you are still typing the opening bracket first, causing the folds to open). If, instead, you use "}<left>{" then you never create an open block.

Comment: Right. I've updated my answer.